# How to render new value of array in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Here I am getting my data from child component and trying to add it into existing array and also I am trying to display it in console using map but the moment I try to to do so I get nothing in console:

```
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import {useState} from 'react';

let App = () => {
  let DataList = ["Apple","Banana"];

  const newList = (data)=>{
      DataList = [...DataList,data];
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Home newList = {newList}/>
      
      { DataList.map((val)=>(
          console.log(val)
        )) 
      }
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You should use `useState` here.

Comment: Do you mean that it *never* logs to the console?  Or it doesn't log whatever gets added to the array to the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use React hooks to make it work, then only your component will rerender

```
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import {useState} from 'react';

let App = () => {
 
  const [DataList, setDataList] = useState(["Apple","Banana"]);

  const newList = (data)=>{
      let temp = [...DataList,data];
      setDataList(temp);
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Home newList = {newList}/>
      
      { DataList.map((val)=>(
          console.log(val)
        )) 
      }
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported this for a reason, use it:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
```

React won't detect changes to any random variable you declare.  So there's no reason for it to re-render the component in the code you have.

*State values* are fundamental to React.  It's how you persist data across renders, and it's how React knows to re-render any given component.  Store your data in state:

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState(["Apple","Banana"]);
```

And use that setter function to update the state:

```
const newList = (data)=>{
  setDataList([...dataList, data]);
};
```

When React sees that state was updated, it will queue a re-render of the component (in this case re-invoking the `App` function internally to the framework) so the new state can be used.